Difference of special token handling of the BertTokenizer's batch_decode() and decode() method?
For BertTokenizer, I am trying to decode sentences produced after tokenization. Here is my code:
from transformers import BertTokenizer

ref = '這件衣服皺巴巴的，幫我燙一下吧。'
our = '衣服皺了，幫我燙一燙'

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('fnlp/bart-base-chinese')

tokenized_our = tokenizer(our, text_target=ref, max_length=300, truncation=True)
print(tokenized_our.labels)

which prints: [101, 21561, 5139, 19633, 11230, 15183, 8924, 8924, 15134, 25818, 9042, 9970, 13953, 4896, 4907, 6458, 3566, 102] (101 = CLS Token, 102 = SEP Token)
Then, I try to decode the same sentence with batch_decode() and decode() function, they produce different output:
print(tokenizer.batch_decode(tokenized_our.input_ids, skip_special_tokens=True))

which produces: ['[ C L S ]', '衣', '服', '皺', '了', '，', '幫', '我', '燙', '一', '燙', '[ S E P ]']. Note spaces are being added to the special tokens like CLS & SEP and the skip_special_tokens=True has no use at all.
For decode() method:
print(tokenizer.decode(tokenized_our.input_ids, skip_special_tokens=True).replace(' ', ''))

which prints: 衣 服 皺 了 ， 幫 我 燙 一 燙. Spaces are added in between Chinese characters, but the special tokens are gone, respecting the skip_special_tokens=True settings. I can further remove the space by replacing them.
My question is: Does the batch_decode() function contain bug, which breaks the special tokens? And what is the difference between batch_decode() and decode()?

It just gets confused because you don't provide a batch: print(tokenizer.batch_decode([tokenized_our.input_ids], skip_special_tokens=True))

Yes, my bad. I overlook the required input.
